# DocumentPicker.pickDirectory() gives the content uri , so how can i convert with folder path /local path in react-native

Tags: react-native

i am using react-native-document-picker for taking the path of directory but the package return content url,but i need folder path / local path

console -  content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ATest
expected output - storage/0/documents /test